# Error in creating samples from the binomial distributions with lapply in R

Tags: r, lapply, distribution, ellipsis

For performing a Monte-Carlo simulation, I want 5000 samples of the binomial and the normal distributions, with different samples sizes (20,30 and 50). My code works perfectly well with the normal (and other distributions that I tested) but it doesn't with the binomial. It says that I didn't specify the prob argument, but I did.

It gives me this error:

```
 Error in x(n, ...) : argument "prob" is missing, with no default
```

My code is this:

```
distribuicoes <- list(normal = c(rnorm, c(mean = 0, sd=1)), 
    binomial = c(rbinom, c(size = 4, prob = 0.5)))

M <- 5000

as <- function(x,n,...){x(n,...)}

for (j in c(20,30,50)){
    dados <- lapply( distribuicoes, function(FUN,M){replicate(M,as(FUN[[1]],FUN[[2]],n=j))},M)
}
```

It's my first question here in stackoverflow, if I didn't explain something well enough, please let me know and I'll correct it. Thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for `rnorm` either. Try mean=100, sd=100.

Comment: It works with rnorm, I just tested it here.

Comment: Are you sure? Does it give random numbers with mean 100 and sd 100? The reason `rnorm` doesn't return an error is because the arguments have defaults while `rbinom` does not.

Comment: Oh, now I see, it takes only the mean argument. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few errors. First, your assignment to `dados` is only going to save the last iteration in the `for` loop. So if you want to keep all iterations, best to define it as a list and then assign the results to each element using `[[]]`. Second (and this is why you get the error), you're not correctly passing named arguments to each function call (`rnorm`, `rbinom`). Third, I think it's better to name your data as follows:

```
distribuicoes <- list(normal = list(dst=rnorm, args=list(mean=0, sd=1)),
                      binomial=list(dst=rbinom, args=list(size=4, prob=0.5)))
```

Then the `as` function should use `do.call`, combining the `...` argument list together with `n` in one named list.

```
as <- function(x, n, ...){
  args <- as.list(c(n=n, unlist(list(...))))
  do.call(x, args)
  }
```

So here's the final code. Replace M with 5000

```
set.seed(123) # remove this later, just for reproducibility here.
M <- 3        # just to see how the output looks.
n <- c(2,3,5) # to show easily on the screen. Replace with your sizes.

dados <- vector("list", length(n))
for(j in seq_along(n)) {
  dados[[j]] <- lapply(distribuicoes, function(f) {
    replicate(M, as(x=f$dst, n=n[j], f$args)) } )
}

dados
```

---

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$normal
        [,1]    [,2]   [,3]
[1,] -0.5605 1.55871 0.1293
[2,] -0.2302 0.07051 1.7151

[[1]]$binomial
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    1    1
[2,]    2    3    0


[[2]]
[[2]]$normal
        [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,] -0.4457  0.4008  1.7869
[2,]  1.2241  0.1107  0.4979
[3,]  0.3598 -0.5558 -1.9666

[[2]]$binomial
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    1    2
[2,]    1    1    2
[3,]    2    2    1


[[3]]
[[3]]$normal
         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,] -1.08570 -0.8185 -0.1294
[2,] -0.08542  0.6849  0.8867
[3,]  1.07061 -0.3201 -0.1514
[4,] -0.14539 -1.3115  0.3298
[5,] -1.16554 -0.5996 -3.2273

[[3]]$binomial
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    4
[3,]    2    2    3
[4,]    2    3    3
[5,]    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just simplify the process, e.g. like this:

```r
lapply(c(20, 30, 50), function(x) list(
    norm=replicate(M, rnorm(x, mean = 0, sd=1)),
    binom=replicate(M, rbinom(x, size = 4, prob = 0.5))))
```

That gives you 3 lists (for n of 20, 30 and 50) for each rnorm and rbinom.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But actually I created a function with the list of distributions as an input, so I can't put them on the lapply manually.